# how to do a sort on var char time column by ASC?

Tags: mysql

I have got a table named  'order_details_child' whose  description as shown below

```
mysql> desc order_details_child;
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| vendor_id        | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| item_id          | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_of_order    | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time_of_order    | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I have got a requirement where i need to retrive records based on **time_of_order** in **ascending** order  ??

```
order by time_of_order asc ?? (First ordered should be shown first)
```

This is the sample record

```
+----------------------+-----------+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+
| order_child_id       | vendor_id | item_id | date_of_order | time_of_order | status |
+----------------------+-----------+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+
| 1410070300301030O1O1 | 1         | 5       | 2014-10-07    | 15:10:30      | NEW    |
+----------------------+-----------+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Could anybody please help me .

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(time_of_order, '%T') ASC

%T = 24hr hh:mm:ss - Did you mean just the time or did you mean date too?

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Thank you so much i have put up a sample record as mentioned in your post .

Comment: just the time is sufficient .